# NextAuth callback not working for verifyRequest when using custom path

Tags: next.js, next-auth

---

**Title: NextAuth callback not working for `verifyRequest` when using custom path**

---

**Body:**

instead of redirecting to verify email page its redirect to homescreen

I'm encountering an issue with NextAuth where the `verifyRequest` callback is not working as expected when I use a custom path. Here's a simplified version of my project structure:

```
.
├── app
│   ├── api
│   │   ├── auth
│   │   │   ├── [...nextauth]
│   │   │   │   └── route.ts
│   │   │   └── sigininemail.ts
│   │   │       └── route.ts
│   │   └── user
│   │       └── route.ts
│   ├── auth
│   │   ├── login
│   │   │   └── page.tsx
│   │   └── verify
│   │       └── page.tsx
```

In the `[...nextauth]/route.ts`, I have defined the `verifyRequest` callback like this:

```js
// [...nextauth]/route.ts
pages:{
  verifyRequest: "/auth/verify",
  signIn: "/auth/login",
},
```

However, if I remove the custom path (`verifyRequest: "/auth/verify"`), it works as expected.

Here is a snippet from `auth/login/page.tsx`:

```js
// auth/login/page.tsx
import { SetStateAction, useCallback, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { signIn, useSession } from "next-auth/react";
import { redirect } from "next/navigation";
import { FaGoogle } from "react-icons/fa";
import Link from "next/link";

const { NEXTAUTH_URL } = process.env;

export default function SignIn() {
  // ... (component logic)

  useEffect(() => {
    // ... (useEffect logic)
  }, [session, status]);

  const handleEmailLogin = useCallback(async () => {
    try {
      await signIn("email", {
        email,
        callbackUrl: process.env.NEXTAUTH_URL as string,
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Email sign-in failed:", error);
    }
  }, [email]);

  // ... (renderContent and other logic)
}
```

```
const verificationPage = async () => {

  return (
    <div className="">
      <div className="flex items-center justify-center mx-auto mt-8 p-8 bg-green-100 border border-green-400 text-green-700">
        <div className="mr-2">
          <svg
            className="fill-current text-green-500 w-6 h-6"
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
            viewBox="0 0 24 24"
          >
            <path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none" />
            <path d="M12 2C6.48 2 2 6.48 2 12s4.48 10 10 10 10-4.48 10-10S17.52 2 12 2zm0 18c-4.41 0-8-3.59-8-8s3.59-8 8-8 8 3.59 8 8-3.59 8-8 8zm-1-13h2v6h-2zm0 8h2v2h-2z" />
          </svg>
        </div>
        <div>
          <p className="font-semibold">Login link sent!</p>
          <p className="text-sm">Check your email for the login link.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default verificationPage;
```

Has anyone else encountered this issue, and does anyone have suggestions for resolving it? Is there something specific I should check in my configuration or code?

I appreciate any insights or guidance on this matter. Thank you!

Comment: The issue I managed to solve it,